# 404 Error Hijacked by Time Warner

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I created a customized 404 page in IIS.  If a user types in the name of one of our employees in the url: www.ourdomain.com/firstname the 404 page grabs the firstname and forwards you to the bio page for that person.  If it doesn't find the string as a name it just serves up our custom 404 error page.

This is working beautifully with one exception.  When you are using Time Warner as your ISP instead of loading the custom 404 page I get an error message that says, "The connection was reset...."  it has a try again button at the bottom.

Any ideas on how I can get Time Warner to serve up my custom 404 error message?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=647281) on the Mozilla Forum, it appears to be ISP's and their greed. Re-routing 404 traffic to pages of their choice likely to improve revenue. It appears the best method is to complain to their customer service however I'm unsure how it will help if its only been a few to complain (so far).

**UPDATE**

It appears someone has [found a way to disable this.](http://blog.perfectspace.com/2008/02/29/how-to-turn-off-disable-road-runners-404-hijackinginterception/)

Comment: I saw that too, but it's from 2008 and my situations a little different.  Before I customized the error, Time Warner was displaying the default server error message.  Plus, I'm not getting a page full of ads like they are describing.

Comment: The disable only works on your individual computer.  Since I'm trying to use the 404 error to forward all my users, I need a solution that will disable it on the entire web.